# Install gems on Windows with RailInstaller: "You must have zlib installed"

Tags: ruby

I'm on Windows, with Ruby 2.0 installed using RailsInstaller.

When I tried to install id3lib-ruby using `gem install id3lib-ruby`, I get the following:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit... 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... 
ERROR:  Error installing id3lib-ruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lstdc++... yes 
checking for main() in -lz... no You must have zlib installed.
*** extconf.rb failed *** 
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  
Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  
You may need configuration options.
```

In mkmf.log, it includes the line:

```
c:/railsinstaller/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have `zlib1.dll` in `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0\bin`, renaming the file to `zlib.dll` doesn't work. So, it looks like RubyInstaller already included the zlib library, but something's still causing the gem install to fail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't work it out. "Fixed" by installing RailsInstaller 2.2.2 (Ruby 1.9.3) and taglib-ruby instead.